# check the type of the only child in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to check if a react element has only one child, and in case that is true and the type of that child is a specific type then inject a prop to it. The only safe way that I found to do it is this:

```
    Children.count(children) === 1
    ? Children.map(children, (c) =>
      c.type === FormRow
        ? cloneElement(c, { compact: c.props?.compact || true })
        : c
    )
    : children
```

It's a bit cumbersome, and the not even clear. Why I'm using Children.map for a single child? Because that is the only safe way react provides to access the opaque children structure.
I read the react API and it is very sparse in terms of children manipulation, very few methods.
Is there any better more obvious way?

I can build an utility function like this:

```js
const isSingleChildOfType = (type, children) => {
  const childrenArr = Children.toArray(children)
  return childrenArr.length === 1 && childrenArr[0].type === type
}
```

But I'm not sure of the implications of turning children into an array. Does it alter the original children or creates a new one?

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of [this](https://mxstbr.blog/2017/02/react-children-deepdive/#converting-children-to-an-array) and [this](https://www.reactenlightenment.com/basic-react-components/6.8.html).

It is valid to use the `.ToArray()` method as you are doing, but you can also access the children using indexing like `[0]` to avoid your map.

---

Some docs also state:

> When there is only a single child, this.props.children will be the single child component itself without the array wrapper. This saves an array allocation.

But  I am unsure how true this is, worth testing with some console.logs in your case.

Comment: Yeah, I also found docs saying that (one was on Chinese automatically translated) but my type checker is warning me that there are lots of cases that do not contain a props field: Iterable, Boolean, Number, String... The same happens when accessing the `[0]` index of the children, there are so many cases that do not have it that it's easier to just use children.map. I really wish react provides more helper functions to work with children